# CMake cannot find source file

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm using ROS kinetic on a Navio2 board, and I've been working on a project in a catkin workspace. I edited the CMakeLists.txt file to add an executable, but every time I attempt to run catkin_make, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at link/CMakeLists.txt:201 (add_executable):
   Cannot find sourcefile:

    link/src/roscomm.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx

CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: roscomm
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "roscomm".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/ros_ws/build
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I know for sure that this file exists, and I've tried using just roscomm.cpp instead of link/src/roscomm.cpp.

---

Edit:

The full path is `~/ros_ws/src/link/src/roscomm.cpp`

The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION )
project(link) 

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS  
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs  
)

catkin_package() 

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(roscomm link/src/roscomm.cpp)
target_link_libraries(roscomm ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Any help would be great, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300573/cmake-cannot-find-source-file/) by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Source file locations are always specified relative to the `CMakeLists.txt` that uses them, so what is the path to `roscomm.cpp` relative to `link/CMakeLists.txt`?

it might help if you show us your `CMakeLists.txt` (ie: the one in the `link` directory).

**Comment by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on 2018-08-14**:
The full path is ~/ros_ws/src/link/src/roscomm.cpp
I've edited the original text so that it can all fit in one place

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Please add this information to your original question text. Use the `edit` button/link for that. Comments are too limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The full path is ~/ros_ws/src/link/src/roscomm.cpp

Without waiting on your edit: have you tried `src/roscomm.cpp`?

If `CMakeLists.txt` is in `~/ros_ws/src/link`, then the path to `roscomm.cpp` relative to your `CMakeLists.txt` would be `src/`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Note also: this is not a ROS issue, but a plain CMake one. For future questions it might be more appropriate to post such questions on a different forum (ie: one more focused on general CMake usage or software development).

**Comment by [Old Meme](https://answers.ros.org/users/36982/old-meme/) on 2018-08-14**:
That seems to have done the trick, thanks!